Proving $f(a)=1 \forall \; a≥ 1/8$ and its Relation to Cardano's Formula
Prove that
$$
f(a)=\left( a + \frac{\sqrt{\frac{8a - 1}{3}} \cdot \left( a + 1 \right)}{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} + \left( a - \frac{\sqrt{\frac{8a - 1}{3}} \cdot \left( a + 1 \right)}{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = 1 \\
 \forall a \ge 1/8
$$
I've tried this:
$$
\text{let} \; x = \left( a + \frac{\sqrt{\frac{8a - 1}{3}} \cdot \left( a + 1 \right)}{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}, \; y = \left( a - \frac{\sqrt{\frac{8a - 1}{3}} \cdot \left( a + 1 \right)}{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}, \; x + y = t \\
\Rightarrow t^3 = (x + y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + 3xy(x+y) = 2a + 3xyt
$$
to find the value of t;
and tried to prove $f'(a) = 0 \; \forall a \ge 1/8$ but all failed.
A background info is that this is related to Cardano's formula, and I also want to know how these two are related.

I struggled to solve this because I didn't recognize that $8a^3 +12a^2 - 6a -1$ can be factored as $(2a-1)^3$. I hope this insight helps you.

I don't know how to handle it by Cardano.
Let $b= \sqrt{8a-1\over 3}$, then $$a = {3b^2+1\over 8}$$
So $$\left( a \pm \frac{\sqrt{\frac{8a - 1}{3}} \cdot \left( a + 1 \right)}{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = \left({3b^2+1\over 8}  \pm \frac{b^3+3b}{8} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=$$
$$=  \left({(1\pm b)^3\over 8}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = {1\pm b\over 2}$$
and thus a result.

Very, very nice!

+1: Very geneous solution; especially compared to mine.

$f(a)=1$ since if $-\frac q2=a$ and $t=1$ is a root of $t^3+pt+q=0$, i.e.
$$\text{if}\quad q=-2a\quad\text{and}\quad p=2a-1,$$
then
$$\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}=\frac{(a+1)^2(8a-1)}{27}.$$

But, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ey0xiff7is

Besides,
$$
\frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27} = - \frac{(a-1)(64a^2 - 11a +1)}{27}
$$
in your case

Oops, thank you @Simon and eugene! Fixed.

Let $x =\left( a + \frac{\sqrt{\frac{8a - 1}{3}} \cdot \left( a + 1 \right)}{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and let $y = \left( a - \frac{\sqrt{\frac{8a - 1}{3}} \cdot \left( a + 1 \right)}{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$.
Note that for $x, y \in \mathbb R$ we must need $8a - 1 \geq 0$ (because of the square root radical) so thus we take $a\geq \frac 18$.
Note that we have $x^3 + y^3 = 2a$ and using difference of squares identity we have $xy = \left(a^2 - \frac{(8a-1)(a+1)^2}{27}\right)^{\frac13} = \frac13\left(27a^2 - (8a-1)(a+1)^2\right)^{\frac13} = \frac13 (1-2a)$
We have $x^3 + y^3 = (x+y)(-3xy + (x+y)^2)$ where we have to show that $t:=x+y=1$. Then we re-write as $2a = t(t^2 - 3xy) \implies 2a = t(t^2 + (2a-1)) \implies t^3 + (2a-1)t - 2a = 0$. Taking $f(t) = t^3 + (2a-1)t - 2a$, we need to find the roots of $f$. It is trivial to see (or guess via RRT) that $f(1) = 0$ so that one can now factor $f$ via polynomial division giving $f(t) = (t-1)\underbrace{(t^2 + t + 2a)}_{g(t)}$. On using the quadratic formula, one finds the roots of $g$ as follows: $$r_{1,2} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-8a}}2$$
For $a > \frac18$, both these values ie $r_1$ and $r_2$ give imaginary outputs because of the square root. Thus, we reject these values since $x+y \in \mathbb R$ and conclude that $t=x+y=1$ for $a \gt \frac18$.
For $a=\frac18$ one finds $r_1 = r_2 = -\frac12$ so we have two possible candidates for the value of $t=x+y$, viz., $1$ and $-\frac12$. One can check via manual evaluation that at $a=\frac18$ is indeed just $1$, thereby proving the desired claim.


Update:
Refer here,
to find the root of a depressed cubic equation $t^3 + pt + q = 0$, the method introduce two variables $u$ and $v$ such that $u+v=t$.
Substitute this in the depressed cubic:
$$u^{3}+v^{3}+(3uv+p)(u+v)+q=0$$
At this point Cardano imposed the condition $3uv+p=0$. This removes the third term in previous equality, leading to the system of equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
u^{3}+v^{3}&=-q\\
uv&=-{\frac {p}{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Knowing the sum and the product of $u^3$ and
$v^{3}$, one deduces that they are the two solutions of the quadratic equation
$$
\begin{aligned}0&=(x-u^{3})(x-v^{3})\\&=x^{2}-(u^{3}+v^{3})x+u^{3}v^{3}\\&=x^{2}-(u^{3}+v^{3})x+(uv)^{3}\end{aligned}
$$
so
$$x^{2}+qx-{\frac {p^{3}}{27}}=0$$
The discriminant of this equation is
$\Delta =q^{2}+{\frac {4p^{3}}{27}}$, and assuming it is positive, real solutions to this equation are (after folding division by 4 under the square root):
$$
-{\frac {q}{2}}\pm {\sqrt {{\frac {q^{2}}{4}}+{\frac {p^{3}}{27}}}}
$$
So (without loss of generality in choosing $u$ or $v$:
$$
u={\sqrt[{3}]{-{\frac {q}{2}}+{\sqrt {{\frac {q^{2}}{4}}+{\frac {p^{3}}{27}}}}}}
$$
$$
v={\sqrt[{3}]{-{\frac {q}{2}}-{\sqrt {{\frac {q^{2}}{4}}+{\frac {p^{3}}{27}}}}}}
$$
So,
$$
t={\sqrt[{3}]{-{q \over 2}+{\sqrt {{q^{2} \over 4}+{p^{3} \over 27}}}}}+{\sqrt[{3}]{-{q \over 2}-{\sqrt {{q^{2} \over 4}+{p^{3} \over 27}}}}}
$$
This works well when $4p^{3}+27q^{2}>0$
this is Cardano's method.
let $p=2a-1$ and $q=-2a$, we get $u+v=t=1$
